# creating Ec2 from existing ec2 instance from terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am given a task to create the similar ec2 instance from existing ec2 instance from the infrastructure in AWS. Is there any way I can import all the setting from existing ec2 and create similar ec2 having the same attributes like vpc, security group, volume type, size and user data.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `aws_instance` [data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/instance.html) to get a reference to the existing instance in your Terraform, after which you could create a new one using the `aws_instance` [resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html), passing all the values from the data source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example code. Enter the instance id which you want to clone

```
variable "AWS_ACCESS_KEY" {}
variable "AWS_SECRET_KEY" {}
variable "AWS_REGION" {}

variable "AWS_INSTANCE_ID" {
  description = "The instance id which you want to copy"
}

provider "aws" {
  access_key = "${var.AWS_ACCESS_KEY}"
  secret_key = "${var.AWS_SECRET_KEY}"
  region = "${var.AWS_REGION}"
}

data "aws_instance" "my_ec2" {
  instance_id = "${var.aws_instance_id}"
}

output "instance_id" {
  value = "${data.aws_instance.my_ec2.id}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "new_instance" {
  ami = "${data.aws_instance.my_ec2.ami}"
  instance_type = "${data.aws_instance.my_ec2.instance_type}"
  subnet_id = "${data.aws_instance.my_ec2.subnet_id}"
  security_groups = "${data.aws_instance.my_ec2.security_groups}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create ami from source ec2 and use that ami as source ami while creating second ec2.

`resource "aws_ami_from_instance" "example" {`
 `name= "terraform-example"` 
  `source_instance_id = "i-xxxxxxxx"`
}